# Need to run ajax calls in serial and then perform function after all are completed in angular

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I have an array of id's.

```
var myArray = [1,2,32,42,5];
```

What I need to do is perform an ajax call in serial fashion on each of these ids. How do I so and then once all are completed run another function?

Right now since I'm doing a `forEach` I'm pretty sure it's running in parallel.

```
myArray.forEach(function(item) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/someUrl/' + item,
      data: {'some' : 'data'}
    })
});

   $scope.reloadUsers();
```

Comment: are requests dependent on each other? Show what you have also...should know better than not to post code

Comment: Yes they need to run in serial fashion.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, as you say, need to run the promises in serial, then you can do this:

```
function postItems(items) {
    var results = [];

    return items
        .reduce(function (last, cur) {
            return last.then(function (result) {
                if (result) { results.push(result); }

                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/someUrl/' + cur,
                    data: {'some' : 'data'}
                });
           });
       }, $q.resolve())
       .then(function (result) {
           if (result) { results.push(result); }

           return results;
       });
}

postItems(myArray).then(function () { return $scope.reloadUsers(); });
```

If you don't actually need the results from your POST operations, then `postItems` can be simplified considerably:

```
function postItems(items) {
    return items
        .reduce(function (last, cur) {
            return last.then(function (result) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/someUrl/' + cur,
                    data: {'some' : 'data'}
                });
           });
       }, $q.resolve())
}
```

You could also create a reusable utility function to run promises in serial and then get the results. The first approach above would then become:

```
function runPromiseSerial(values, action) {
    var results = [];

    if(values.length === 0) { return $q.resolve(results); }

    var start = $q.resolve();

    return values
        .reduce(function (last, cur) {
            return last.then(function (result) {
                if (last !== start) { results.push(result); }

                return action(cur);
            });
       }, start)
       .then(function (result) {
           results.push(result);

           return results;
       });
}

function postItems(items) {
    return runPromiseSerial(items, function (item) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/someUrl/' + item,
            data: {'some' : 'data'}
        });            
    });
}

postItems(myArray).then(function () { return $scope.reloadUsers(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain asynchronous calls like ajax calls using jQuery's deferred object and using 'then'.

```
$(function() {
    var delay = 3,
        span = $('span'),
        posts = [1,2,32,42,5],
        looper = $.Deferred().resolve();

    $.each(posts, function(i, data) {
        looper = looper.then(function() {
            return $.ajax({
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify(data),
                    delay: delay
                },
                method: 'post',
                url: '/echo/json/',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(response) {
                span.append('Response:<br />');
                span.append(response + '<br />');
                $('span').append('Waiting ' + delay + ' seconds<br /><br />');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can watch an example on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4cFv/). BUT Ajax is replaced with timeout function there

Hope this will help

---

### For fiddle use this code

Copy below code to watch it working for your scenario.

```
$(function() {
    var delay = 3000,
        span = $('span'),
        posts = [1,2,32,42,5],
        asyncFunction = function(data) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            setTimeout(function() {
                span.append('Argument:<br />');
                span.append(data + '<br />');

                $('span').append('Waiting ' + delay + ' milliseconds<br /><br />');

                deferred.resolve();
            }, delay);

            return deferred.promise();
        },
        looper = $.Deferred().resolve();

    $.each(posts, function(i, data) {
        looper = looper.then(function() {
            return asyncFunction(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't run the promises in serial. And OP never said he was using jQuery.

Comment: I added it in case as an alternative approach but your solution seems fair enough to do this with Angular